# Putting text on images in python in languages other than english

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am working on a computer vision project and am in its last stage.

I require to display text from languages like Hindi, Telugu , Tamil etc on the images.

I even downloaded the ttf (true type font) but it display the text on the image still as '????' or as boxes. I tried putting the text using both openCv 'putText' method and using PIL draw text function but no help.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Mind showing code you wrote? As simple as possible!

Comment: Use cv2.Puttext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PIL you can do it by specifying the font, Here is a sample that works to display hindi.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

fn = "Image.png"

img = Image.open(fn)
 
I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
myFont = ImageFont.truetype('NirmalaB.ttf', 65, layout_engine=ImageFont.Layout.RAQM)
I1.text((20, 36), "हेलो वर्ल्ड", fill=(0, 255, 0), font=myFont)

 
img.save("text_"+fn)
```

For this to work you also need to download a font that supports hindi. Here is a font that i have found that works [Here](https://freefontsdownload.net/free-nirmalab-font-138080.htm)

Comment: The key to the above code is using librqm for the text layout engine. You will need to ensure that it and its dependencies are installed.

Comment: To see if libraqm is installed and available:
`PIL.features.check_feature(feature='raqm')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the language that OCR is detecting you probably need to use [PyTesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

In this case, you have a function like

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-image.jpg'), lang='fra')
```

This function works with openCv and you can use both at the same time. You can even manipulate the image with OpenCV and read the characters in a specific language with PyTesseract. For example:

```
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = pytesseract.image_to_osd(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

Here, you are using a blue_green_red to red_green_blue change for a basic manipulation and then passing it to the osd algorithm from PyTesseract.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I need to put text on an image rather than detecting it. :(